# Trying to sub-type classes using generics

Tags: java, generics

I am having problems trying to create a sub-type class, and calling its superconstructor with an ArrayList of objects of a certain generic type. I am trying to get this code to work. I want my SubTypes to ONLY accept a list of **GenericObjects** that are of type **X**.

```
    public class SubType extends SuperType{

        public SubType(ArrayList<GenericObject<Y>> g) {
            super(g);
        }
    }

    public class SuperType {

        public ArrayList<GenericObject<?>> data = new ArrayList<GenericObject<? extends X>>();

        public SuperType(ArrayList<GenericObject<? extends X>> series) {

            data.addAll(series);
        }
    }


    class GenericObject<T extends X>{}
    class X{};
    class Y extends X{};
```

I get an error where the super(g) is called. It says that

> The constructor
>   TestGenerics.SuperType(ArrayList>)
>   is undefined

Thats kind of strange because I thought that Generics allowed this kind of thing.

If I don't pass through an ArrayList of my generic object, and just pass the generic object through then it is OK.

```
public class SubType extends SuperType{

    public SubType(GenericObject<Y> g) {
        super(g);
    }
}

public class SuperType {

    public ArrayList<GenericObject<?>> data = new ArrayList<GenericObject<? extends X>>();

    public SuperType(GenericObject<? extends X> series) {

        data.add(series);
    }
}

class GenericObject<T extends X>{
}

class X{};
class Y extends X{};
```

The above works perfectly. Is there any way to get the first example to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `ArrayList<Child>` does not extend `ArrayList<Parent>` even if `Child` extends `Parent`.
However, you were on the right track before, because `ArrayList<Child>` does extend `ArrayList<? extends Parent>`.

**You just need to repeat your `? extends ...` pattern one more time**, like this:

```
public SuperType(ArrayList<? extends GenericObject<? extends X>> series) {
    data.addAll(series);
}
```

This compiles fine for me.

---

**UPDATE**: The full code would look like this:

```
public class SubType extends SuperType{

    public SubType(ArrayList<GenericObject<Y>> g) {
        super(g);
    }
}

public class SuperType {

    public ArrayList<GenericObject<?>> data = new ArrayList<GenericObject<? extends X>>();

    public SuperType(ArrayList<? extends GenericObject<? extends X>> series) {

        data.addAll(series);
    }
}


class GenericObject<T extends X>{}
class X{};
class Y extends X{};
```

Comment: @OliverWatkins Right here, I added it back. I had removed it because it was the exact same as your code. I just changed the `SuperType` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Are you perhaps in search of this solution?

```
class SubType extends SuperType<Y> {

    public SubType(List<GenericObject<Y>> g) {
        super(g);
    }
}

class SuperType<T extends X> {

    public List<GenericObject<T>> data = new ArrayList<GenericObject<T>>();

    public SuperType(List<GenericObject<T>> series) {
        data.addAll(series);
    }
}

class GenericObject<T extends X>{}
class X{};
class Y extends X{};
```

Comment: possibly. I dont think i can add generics to the sub and super type. I'll get back to you

Comment: No need to make these type generic IMHO, it is kinda overkill.